# Form won't validate with an anchor section

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I have a form on a free standing contact form, however when I attempt to use it at the bottom of a scrolling page or in a section with an anchor it won't visually validate. In other words the error messages won't appear. The form will send an email if all the required fields are filled.But visually nothing happens!?
http://patrickmchugh.com/test/

To see how it should work, please see a free standing contact.php  patrickmchugh.com/test/contact.php This is how the error messages should work.

```
<?php   
// check for form submission - if it doesn't exist then send back to contact form  
if (!isset($_POST['save']) || $_POST['save'] != 'contact') { 
    header('Location: index.php#content'); exit; 
} 

// get the posted data 
$name = $_POST['contact_name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['contact_email']; 
$subject = $_POST['contact_subject'];
$message = $_POST['contact_message']; 

// check that a name was entered 
if (empty($name)) 
    $error = 'You must enter your name.'; 
// check that an email address was entered 
elseif (empty($email_address))  
    $error = 'You must enter your email address.'; 
// check for a valid email address 
elseif (!preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/', $email_address)) 
    $error = 'You must enter a valid email address.'; 
// check that a message was entered 
elseif (empty($message)) 
    $error = 'You must enter a message.'; 

// check if an error was found - if there was, send the user back to the form 
if (isset($error)) { 
    header('Location: index.php?e='.urlencode($error).'#content2'); exit;
} 

// write the email content 
$email_content = "Name: $name\n"; 
$email_content .= "Email Address: $email_address\n"; 
$email_content .= "Subject: $subject\n";
$email_content .= "Message:\n\n$message"; 

// send the email 
mail ("patrick@patrickmchugh.com", "Enquiry from Connolly O'Neill Website", $email_content); 

// send the user back to the form 
header('Location: index.php?s='.urlencode('Thank you for your message.').'#contact2'); exit;
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After submit form your url will be `?e=You+must+enter+your+name.#content2` so
you need to get and echo error on your form page like:-

```
if(isset($_GET['e'])) {
  echo $_GET['e'];  // or echo urldecode($_GET['e']);
}
```

Same for after successfully submit like:-

```
if(isset($_GET['s'])) {
  echo $_GET['s'];  // or echo urldecode($_GET['s']);
}
```

Comment: Rakesh Sharma I don't understand, am I swapping out code or just adding this?

Comment: put my code where you want to show errors and msg then see result

Comment: Like this?? // check that a name was entered 
    if (empty($name)) 
        $error = 'You must enter your name.'; 
  if(isset($_GET['e'])) {
  echo $_GET['e'];  // or echo urldecode($_GET['e']);
}

Comment: only use given code like <?php if(isset($_GET['e'])) {
  echo $_GET['e'];  // or echo urldecode($_GET['e']);
}?>

Comment: Sorry, I was putting it in to the php code. I realise now I need to put it into the index file. Much obliged. Thanks